# How to determine behavior of binaries in NuGet package

Tags: c#, mef, nuget-package

There is this big solution I'm working on, where I turned a lot of the projects into NuGet packages. The packages were created via a .nuproj file in a separate solution in VS.

Everything works fine, except for the following:
At bootstrap I load some catalogs for MEF to be able to import them, which worked perfectly when I worked with the original projects, but now the needed DLLs (which come from the a package) don't make it to the bin\Debug\Modules folder.

Is there a way to make NuGet copy its content to the Modules folder? (and not to the root path)

I tried using the different kinds of sub-folders inside the package with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best solution for this matter is the following:

Take the files that need to be loaded and put them on the content folder. This can be done simply:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include=" {here go the needed files} " />
</ItemGroup>
```

The content folder just holds the files, but it **does not** copy them to the output folder on the client project. In order to copy them to the desired output, a .targets file can be used, just like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CopyToOutput" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\**\*.*"/>    
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy 
      SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
      DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(OutDir)/%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)')"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Keep in mind that the targets file name and the ID of the NuGet have to be equal for the targets file to be added to the project.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a target of `content/Modules`.  Anything in the `content` directory is copied in to the `bin` directory on build.

If you were trying to use the special "convention based" folders, like `lib/net45`, those are directories that cause Visual Studio to automatically create an assembly reference when the package is installed. You shouldn't use those for regular content files.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) for more details.